# images not resizing good on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm developing a website and i'm using wow slider.

this is my website:

http://forum.freekerstudio.com/

For desktop it is working fine, when you go to website it is showing a gallery and music is playng, everything is write.

I have a situation when i'm trying to go to de website on the mobile:

- the music is not playing like on desktop
- images are not resizing good on mobile

could you please give me some advice for this issue.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>V1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Made with WOW Slider - Create beautiful, responsive image sliders in a few clicks. Awesome skins and animations. Jquery slider" />

    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section --> <!-- add to the <head> of your page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

</head>
<body style="background-color:#000;margin:0">

    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section --> <!-- add to the <body> of your page -->
    <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
        <li><img src="data1/images/09052014img_20952.jpg" alt="09052014-IMG_2095-2" title="09052014-IMG_2095-2" id="wows1_0"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/03052014_s8d5127.jpg" alt="03052014-_S8D5127" title="03052014-_S8D5127" id="wows1_1"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/13062014img_6777modifier2.jpg" alt="13062014-IMG_6777-Modifier-2" title="13062014-IMG_6777-Modifier-2" id="wows1_2"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/12062014img_6394.jpg" alt="12062014-IMG_6394" title="12062014-IMG_6394" id="wows1_3"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/03052014_s8d51582.jpg" alt="03052014-_S8D5158-2" title="03052014-_S8D5158-2" id="wows1_4"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/_dsc65483.jpg" alt="_DSC6548-3" title="_DSC6548-3" id="wows1_5"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/_mg_42682.jpg" alt="_MG_4268-2" title="_MG_4268-2" id="wows1_6"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/_s8d0871.jpg" alt="_S8D0871" title="_S8D0871" id="wows1_7"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/sanstitre473.jpg" alt="sans-titre-47-3" title="sans-titre-47-3" id="wows1_8"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/livre_support4562.jpg" alt="livre support-456-2" title="livre support-456-2" id="wows1_9"/></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/livresupport6455.jpg" alt="livre-support-645-5" title="livre-support-645-5" id="wows1_10"/></li>
        <li><a href="http://wowslider.com"><img src="data1/images/sanstitre4732.jpg" alt="http://wowslider.com/" title="sans-titre-473-2" id="wows1_11"/></a></li>
        <li><img src="data1/images/skullfreekerhd.jpg" alt="Skull-Freeker-HD" title="Skull-Freeker-HD" id="wows1_12"/></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
        <a href="#" title="09052014-IMG_2095-2"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/09052014img_20952.jpg" alt="09052014-IMG_2095-2"/>1</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="03052014-_S8D5127"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/03052014_s8d5127.jpg" alt="03052014-_S8D5127"/>2</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="13062014-IMG_6777-Modifier-2"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/13062014img_6777modifier2.jpg" alt="13062014-IMG_6777-Modifier-2"/>3</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="12062014-IMG_6394"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/12062014img_6394.jpg" alt="12062014-IMG_6394"/>4</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="03052014-_S8D5158-2"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/03052014_s8d51582.jpg" alt="03052014-_S8D5158-2"/>5</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="_DSC6548-3"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/_dsc65483.jpg" alt="_DSC6548-3"/>6</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="_MG_4268-2"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/_mg_42682.jpg" alt="_MG_4268-2"/>7</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="_S8D0871"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/_s8d0871.jpg" alt="_S8D0871"/>8</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="sans-titre-47-3"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/sanstitre473.jpg" alt="sans-titre-47-3"/>9</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="livre support-456-2"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/livre_support4562.jpg" alt="livre support-456-2"/>10</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="livre-support-645-5"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/livresupport6455.jpg" alt="livre-support-645-5"/>11</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="sans-titre-473-2"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/sanstitre4732.jpg" alt="sans-titre-473-2"/>12</span></a>
        <a href="#" title="Skull-Freeker-HD"><span><img src="data1/tooltips/skullfreekerhd.jpg" alt="Skull-Freeker-HD"/>13</span></a>
    </div></div>
<audio src="engine1/freekersite_master_.mp3"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/swfobject.js"></script><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.net">jquery slider</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.5</div>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    /*
 *  generated by WOW Slider 8.5
 *  template Galaxy
 */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&subset=latin,cyrillic,latin-ext);
#wowslider-container1 { 
    display: block;
    zoom: 1; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:none;
    margin:0px auto 0px;
    z-index:90;
    text-align:left; /* reset align=center */
    font-size: 10px;
    text-shadow: none; /* fix some user styles */

    /* reset box-sizing (to boostrap friendly) */
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box; 
}
* html #wowslider-container1{ width:960px }
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul{
    position:relative;
    width: 10000%; 
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    overflow: visible;
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul li{
    position: relative;
    width:1%;
    height:100%;
    line-height:0; /*opera*/
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    /*font-size:0;*/
    padding:0 0 0 0 !important;
    margin:0 0 0 0 !important;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    max-height:none;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border:none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images ul a{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-height:none;
    display:block;
    color:transparent;
}
#wowslider-container1 img{
    max-width: none !important;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images .ws_list img,
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images > div > img{
    width:100%;
    border:none 0;
    max-width: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_images > div > img {
    max-height:none;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_images iframe {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws-title > div {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#wowslider-container1 a{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    outline: none; 
    border: none; 
}

#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets { 
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:70;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets div{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size: 0px;
}
/* compatibility with Joomla styles */
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets a {
    line-height: 0;
}

#wowslider-container1  .ws_script{
    display:none;
}
#wowslider-container1 sound, 
#wowslider-container1 object{
    position:absolute;
}

/* prevent some of users reset styles */
#wowslider-container1 .ws_effect {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_photoItem {
    border: 2em solid #fff;
    margin-left: -2em;
    margin-top: -2em;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_cube_side {
    background: #000;
}


#wowslider-container1.ws_gestures {
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABwSURBVEjH7ZJBEsAgCAMT/v/n9NCOSqe2oD2yNx1JggB4BCEFWyFASP2KMQE7ywWhe/tTRGCGogLk02tFctiW/SUgaMyQG4PdPzDn31rQbMb8FiAXgvsEJNax1yVlVGAjA93apP3HFhZTGIqiKH7iADB6HxPlHdNVAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOmNyZWF0ZQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjEwKzAyOjAwm7WiFAAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTptb2RpZnkAMjAxNC0wNy0wN1QxMzo0OToxMCswMjowMOroGqgAAAAASUVORK5CYII="), move;
}
#wowslider-container1.ws_gestures.ws_grabbing {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAABaSURBVEjH7ZMxCkAhDEOT8u9/5TpJ+xWkFse8IYutJgEB8RCHL1qCc90BEFnT6QH7mwgFHBUf8wJyS1TDLuc3vmighx37LZdIth3E5hKj9n6O0HRh+oJCiFcMxRUUDxR1CTMAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTQtMDctMDdUMTM6NDk6MzgrMDI6MDDqf+sOAAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDE0LTA3LTA3VDEzOjQ5OjM4KzAyOjAwmyJTsgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), move;
}

/* hide controls when video start play */
#wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_bullets,
#wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_fullscreen,
#wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_next,
#wowslider-container1.ws_video_playing .ws_prev {
    display: none;
}


/* youtube/vimeo buttons */
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 55;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_youtube,
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_vimeo {
    display: block;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn div {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(./playvideo.png);
    background-size: 200%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 7em;
    height: 5em;
    margin-left: -3.5em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_youtube div {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_youtube:hover div {
    background-position: 100% 0;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_vimeo div {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_video_btn.ws_vimeo:hover div {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause.ws_hide {
    display: none !important;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets { 
    padding: 5px 0; 
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a { 
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;

    background-image: url(./bullet.png);
    float: left; 
    text-indent: -4000px; 
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0px;
    color:transparent;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover, #wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a.ws_selbull{
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next, #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-4.2em;
    z-index:60;
    width: 4.2em;   
    height: 8.4em;
    background-image: url(./arrows.png);
    background-size: 200%;
    opacity: 1;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next{
    background-position: 0 0;
    right: 0;
}
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev {
    background-position: 100% 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*playpause*/
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause {
    width: 8.4em;
    height: 8.4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4.2em;
    margin-top: -4.2em;
    z-index: 59;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_pause {
    background-image: url(./pause.png);
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_play {
    background-image: url(./play.png);
}/* bottom right */
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets {
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 10px;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws-title{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    font: 2.1em 'Roboto Condensed', 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 0;
    padding:0.5em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    color:#000; 
    z-index: 50;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-transform: none;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title div,#wowslider-container1 .ws-title span{
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:1;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title div{
    display:block;
    margin-top:0.6em;
    font-size: 0.571em;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title span{
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}#wowslider-container1 a.ws_next,
#wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev,
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause {
    display:none;
}

* html #wowslider-container1 a.ws_next,* html #wowslider-container1 a.ws_prev{display:block}

#wowslider-container1:hover a.ws_next,
#wowslider-container1:hover a.ws_prev,
#wowslider-container1:hover .ws_playpause {
    display:block
}#wowslider-container1 .ws_images > ul{
    animation: wsBasic 52s infinite;
    -moz-animation: wsBasic 52s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: wsBasic 52s infinite;
}
@keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 3.85%{left:-0%} 7.69%{left:-100%} 11.54%{left:-100%} 15.38%{left:-200%} 19.23%{left:-200%} 23.08%{left:-300%} 26.92%{left:-300%} 30.77%{left:-400%} 34.62%{left:-400%} 38.46%{left:-500%} 42.31%{left:-500%} 46.15%{left:-600%} 50%{left:-600%} 53.85%{left:-700%} 57.69%{left:-700%} 61.54%{left:-800%} 65.38%{left:-800%} 69.23%{left:-900%} 73.08%{left:-900%} 76.92%{left:-1000%} 80.77%{left:-1000%} 84.62%{left:-1100%} 88.46%{left:-1100%} 92.31%{left:-1200%} 96.15%{left:-1200%} }
@-moz-keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 3.85%{left:-0%} 7.69%{left:-100%} 11.54%{left:-100%} 15.38%{left:-200%} 19.23%{left:-200%} 23.08%{left:-300%} 26.92%{left:-300%} 30.77%{left:-400%} 34.62%{left:-400%} 38.46%{left:-500%} 42.31%{left:-500%} 46.15%{left:-600%} 50%{left:-600%} 53.85%{left:-700%} 57.69%{left:-700%} 61.54%{left:-800%} 65.38%{left:-800%} 69.23%{left:-900%} 73.08%{left:-900%} 76.92%{left:-1000%} 80.77%{left:-1000%} 84.62%{left:-1100%} 88.46%{left:-1100%} 92.31%{left:-1200%} 96.15%{left:-1200%} }
@-webkit-keyframes wsBasic{0%{left:-0%} 3.85%{left:-0%} 7.69%{left:-100%} 11.54%{left:-100%} 15.38%{left:-200%} 19.23%{left:-200%} 23.08%{left:-300%} 26.92%{left:-300%} 30.77%{left:-400%} 34.62%{left:-400%} 38.46%{left:-500%} 42.31%{left:-500%} 46.15%{left:-600%} 50%{left:-600%} 53.85%{left:-700%} 57.69%{left:-700%} 61.54%{left:-800%} 65.38%{left:-800%} 69.23%{left:-900%} 73.08%{left:-900%} 76.92%{left:-1000%} 80.77%{left:-1000%} 84.62%{left:-1100%} 88.46%{left:-1100%} 92.31%{left:-1200%} 96.15%{left:-1200%} }

#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets  a img{
    text-indent:0;
    display:block;
    bottom:20px;
    left:-77px;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    max-width:none;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets a:hover img{
    visibility:visible;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div div{
    height:48px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div {
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:153px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#wowslider-container1  .ws_bullets .ws_bulframe{
    display:none;
    bottom:26px;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe span{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-11px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    left:77px;
    background:url(./triangle.png);
    width:13px;
    height:7px;
}#wowslider-container1 .ws_bulframe div div{
    height: auto;
}

@media all and (max-width:760px) {
    #wowslider-container1 .ws_fullscreen {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width:400px){
    #wowslider-container1 .ws_controls,
    #wowslider-container1 .ws_bullets,
    #wowslider-container1 .ws_thumbs{
        display: none
    }
}
```

---

```
    #wowslider-container1 .ws_hovershow {
    /*display: none !important; */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

#wowslider-container1:hover .ws_hovershow {
    /*display: block !important;*/
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    transition:opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

/*playpause*/
#wowslider-container1 .ws_playpause {
    width: 18px;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    z-index: 59;
}

#wowslider-container1 .pause {
    background-image: url(./pause.png);
}

#wowslider-container1 .play {
    background-image: url(./play.png);
}

#wowslider-container1 .pause:hover, #wowslider-container1 .play:hover {
    background-position: 100% 100% !important;
}

#wowslider-container1 .ws_fullscreen {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 15px;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    z-index: 59;
    background-image: url(./fullscreen.png);
}

div#ws_fullscreen:-moz-full-screen #wowslider-container1 {
    width: 95% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: inherit;
}

div#ws_fullscreen:-webkit-full-screen #wowslider-container1 {
    width: 95% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: inherit;
}

div#ws_fullscreen:fullscreen #wowslider-container1 {
    width: 95% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: inherit;
}

div#ws_fullscreen:-moz-full-screen {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
}

div#ws_fullscreen:-webkit-full-screen {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
}

div#ws_fullscreen:fullscreen {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code so that we may help identify the issue, as well as solutions you have tried - expecting us to visit the website and solve the problem is not acceptable

Comment: I apologize for the lack of professionalism, i'm not asking to give my solution, but some advice. Maybe i need to add some mediaqueries i'm not sur

Comment: (a bit offtopic) The thing you're doing with all the images in background is a total unnecessary overkill. It would be more performant (and even more pleasant to the eye) if the images in background would stay still while the current one is zooming in/out. It's OK to do it once, on start for example- to animate the displacement / arrangement of all the images, but otherwise...